# Can this syntax be minified in MySQL?

Tags: sql, mysql

This is my working query

I have a table with 2 unique columns ain (not null) + schemecode (can be null)

case1:

```
SET @ain = '000002304000134'; 
SET @sc = NULL; 
SELECT * FROM account
WHERE (ain=@ain AND Schemecode=@sc AND @sc IS NOT NULL) OR (ain=@ain AND Schemecode IS NULL AND @sc IS NULL)
```

Case 2:

```
SET @ain = '000002304000134'; 
SET @sc = '00000'; 
SELECT * FROM account
WHERE (ain=@ain AND Schemecode=@sc AND @sc IS NOT NULL) OR (ain=@ain AND Schemecode IS NULL AND @sc IS NULL)
```

case 3:

```
SET @ain = '000002304000134'; 
SET @sc = '00001';
SELECT * FROM account
WHERE (ain=@ain AND Schemecode=@sc AND @sc IS NOT NULL) OR (ain=@ain AND Schemecode IS NULL AND @sc IS NULL)
```

For all 3 scenarious working query.Above syntax look lenghty.Is syntax can be minified please let me know i want to use in ef core (lambda ) and as well as plain sql

Comment: The above query works fine..i have 2 columns unique (ain,Schemecode) here scheme code can be nullable .. if i put Schemecode=@sc not works nullable ,, i write lenghy query ,.. My question is above query can be minified

Comment: What do you mean when using *"ef core (lambda )"* words? `ExecuteUpdate`?

Comment: I'd keep the lengthy code. Portable and generic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the null-safe comparison operator `<=>`:

```
SELECT * FROM account
WHERE ain=@ain AND Schemecode<=>@sc
```

Note that your `AND @sc IS NOT NULL` could have been left out; if the `=@sc` was true, you already know @sc cannot be null.

Comment: @thanks is it works with ef core?

Comment: No idea what that even is, but to get help with it you likely need to show your ef core code

Comment: ok.<=> operator works in sql lite

Comment: What does sqlite have to do with it?

Comment: I have both my sql & sql lite db so asked

Comment: As far as I know sqlite does *not* have `<=>`.  For sqlite you'd do `Schemecode is @sc`

Comment: Thanks  for the clue ..I will check with ef core ..